BLE connectivity in Android Phone
I am developing an mobile app in the android. My app connect with device and operate which working fine when my phone is not connected with Car Bluetooth.
As soon as my phone connect with Car Bluetooth then it stop operating the my device and always give error for connecting with device failed.
Does any one have feedback on this?

Please add the exact error message you are receiving as well as the relevant parts of your apps source code.
